# How to Implementing StackMob in existing Core Data Sqlite iOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, stackmob

Looking at BaaS providers to sync client data between devices.  I like the StackMob implementation but I don't understand if and how to implement StackMob into an existing application using Core Data and Sqlite.  Maintaining the existing DB is essential for backward compatibility.

Can someone explain how to do this or point me to documentation that describes the process?

Comment: StackMob provides lots and lots of documentation on their site, in very easy to find locations. There's even a page called "StackMob and Core Data". That's probably a really good starting point.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I Already looked but it's all Greenfield.